# Firebase Database Billing Usage

Tags: firebase

I've just used Firebase & I have 2 questions that hopefully can be answered here.

I was wondering, is the quota for reading 50,000?

And if I exceed that limit, will I have to pay even though I haven't added a credit card or anything to my account.
I want to know this because I don't want to have to pay because I haven't even added a credit card.

If I exceed the quota, will the feature be disabled or will I have to pay?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about quotas on the Spark free tier, the daily quota is 50,000 document reads per day, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#pricing_by_location).  If you exceed that quota, queries will fail until the quota is reset the next day.

If you have further question about billing, you should [ask Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) rather than posting to Stack Overflow.